# Windbg cannot download any symbol files

Tags: windows, windbg

I just downloaded Windbg Preview and I wrote a small demo console application. When I tried to debug it, Windbg only printed some lines of text and then got stuck. The text is:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.22473.1005 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: D:\a.exe

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Deferred                                       cache*c:\mysymbol
Deferred                                       srv*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: srv*;cache*c:\mysymbol;srv*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00400000 00411000   image00400000
ModLoad: 775f0000 77793000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 76b90000 76c80000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNEL32.DLL
ModLoad: 762c0000 764d4000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 77340000 773ff000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 6eb40000 6ec1d000   D:\C\mingw\bin\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
ModLoad: 6fe40000 6ffb4000   D:\C\mingw\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
(853c.79a4): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
```

And I found that it was downloading the symbol file `wntdll.pdb`, and then I cannot do any operations. What's more, I think it is caused by the network: one reason is I'm in China mainland, the Great Firewall blocks almost all connections from another country; the other is my laptop's network services are BROKEN! They can't do anything. I found out that since a night in 2021.12.27 (year.month.day), after my laptop lost power unexpectedly, the network services couldn't work unless I use wired network. In the other hand, my laptop cannot connect to WiFi.

In recent days, I was finding why they can't work. Finally I found that the service `WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service` cannot start. When I tried to start the service with the command `net start WinHttpAutoProxySvc`, it did not start and gave me an error code: 5 (Access is denied). It also caused these questions (I don't know if they are actually caused by it):

- Taskbar got stuck when I use wired network and restart explorer.exe;
- Search bar cannot use, I can ONLY see dots;
- Windows cannot update;
- Edge cannot download some files.

To sum up, I have two questions to ask:

1. Why can't Windbg Preview download any symbol files?
2. Why can't I connect to WiFi after my laptop lost power unexpectedly?
   I am very anxious to know the answers. If your answers CAN help me, you will be appreciated.
   Thank you!

Comment: My experiennce with the Great firewall in 2008 was: 1. you access an URL and get no response 2. you try again later and it works. My conclusion was that the file contents were scanned in the meanwhile and the file has been identified as "China compliant". So: maybe just wait a bit, or switch to the https version of the URL.

Comment: The other questions regarding Wifi loss after power failure are mostly IT questions, not programming questions. They are off-topic for this site. Power failure can cause data corruption on your hard disk and thus affect Wifi drivers etc. Power failure with a power spike can also destroy hardware, so maybe Wifi is physically broken. Try `sfc /scannow`, try a system restore point, maybe roll back to a backup from before 2021-12-27, maybe reinstall from scratch (backup your data first).

Comment: For the hardware issues, maybe ask on superuser.com

Comment: But I waited for 2 hours but it still didn't download any, `sfc /scannow` told me my laptop was OK, and I don't have a system restore point :( However, I thank for the link you gave me, I hope I can find the answer there.

Comment: On the other hand, can you tell me where Windbg Preview stores the symbols? Maybe I can download the symbol file by Internet (Chrome can download files).

Comment: `cache*c:\mysymbol` that's where they are put in your case. But that folder has a special structure. Each file needs to be put in a specific folder matching some hash that is stored in the PDB. It's not as simple as copying it somewhere. The tool that can do this is called `symstore`.

Comment: You mean that I should put them like `C:\mysymbol\ntdll.pdb\46F6F5C30E7147E46F2A953A5DAF201A1\ntdll.pdb`? So, how to get the hash of the file? Is the way just like: read the binary text and get the hash by any language (support hash, like Python's hash() and Java's hashCode() )? I found the ntdll.pdb in Windbg in Windows Kits.

Comment: Sorry, it's not that simple. I doubt Microsoft has made the algorithm public. The symstore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symstore) page says it might depend on timestamp, size, signature, age, ... [`symstore add ...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symstore-transactions) can add symbols to that location.

Comment: @ThomasWeller The "hash" is in fact the PDB signature (a GUID) of the binary, which you can find inside the debug directory in the binary itself. The structure at this location is a `CV_INFO_PDB70` (starts with `RSDS` signature).

Comment: @Neitsa: okay, now I am worried that Sam-zhuang attempts to write his own tool for sorting PDBs. I wanted to avoid that ;-)

Comment: ;) did that myself so I could download PDBs on linux...

Comment: @ThomasWeller I do not want to write it at all, because I'm a little bit lazy and I am only a middle school student so that I'm not able to do that. I want to repair the WiFi function of my laptop, not WinDbg Preview. :)

Comment: All in all, when I want to find the reason, I tried to debug `svchost.exe`, so I want to repair WinDbg Preview to debug it

Comment: I think SuperUser.com or your laptop vendor is a better source for solutions. It is not a surprise that some laptop models require you to install extra pieces of software (Wifi adapter drivers for example) so as to be able to connect to any Wifi hotspot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days, I found a very easy way: open settings, reset network, and finally reboot.